# Redirect user immediately on logout using Angular and Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, angular-meteor

In a Meteor app that uses angular, there is a state that requires that the user is logged in.

This is currently done using [`$meteor.requireUser()`](http://angular.meteorhub.org/api/auth)

```
function run($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
        if(error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
            $state.go('login')
        }
    })
}
```

and

```
.state('secretzone', {
    url: '/secret/zone',
    templateUrl: 'client/secret/views/zone.ng.html',
    controller: 'SecretZoneCtrl',
    resolve: {
        "currentUser": ["$meteor", function($meteor){
            return $meteor.requireUser();
        }]
    }
})
```

**Problem:** When the user is currently on the `secretzone` state and logs out, he should be redirected to the `login` state but instead still remains on the same page until he refreshes the page.

How can we force the user to be redirected to the `login` state the moment he logs out if he is already on a page that requires him to be authenticated?

Can this be done just by using only the UI Router, just like how it was easily achieved using Iron Router when Blaze is used?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to call $state.reload() in your logout success handler.

This will, as the name suggests, reload the current state, so in this case secretzone and that will cause the resolve logic to be invoked and therefore throw the error to get picked up by your $stateChangeError handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logout function, why not calling `$state.go('login')` directly in that function?

Comment: The user may log out when he is on a page that does not require him to be authenticated. In this case, there is no need to redirect to the `login` state

Answer (score 0):

You can $watch or Meteor.Autorun the currentUser variable and add a logic inside that redirects to the login screen.

If you are using $rootScope.currentUser then use $watch and if you are using Meteor.currentUser use Meteor.autorun